# Rails controller aliasing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose we have a scaffold called City. In which you can add and remove city.

Now I want to have a controller called /ajax/city, in which only json is served, now is there a easier way of doing this?

Right now, I am just copying and pasting the City controller and renaming the namespace to Ajax::City.

The idea right now is to keep the main namespace clean, and I have disabled json from the main namespace routes.

Answer (score 0):

Having a path called ajax/city is not the standard way of doing this.
It does not directly answer your question but you would generally serve JSON with the same controller.

For example you would receive json through /cities.json or a particular one with /cities/1.json. When doing Ajax requests this is served automatically without the extension if you do something such as the following.

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json {
        render :json => @cities
    }
end
```